# How can be Interop of MSXML Node in C++/CLI as XMLTextWriter or related XML Usability

Tags: visual-c++, interop, c++-cli, msxml

I have some native code which generates a native XML node of MSXML. I need that root node in C++/CLI to be used as XMLTextWriter or in any form of XML in C++/CLI.

Is there any interop available for an MSXML Node in C++/CLI?

Answer (score 0):

No, MSXML and System.Xml are different code bases. You have to get the xml content of the node in MSXML via .xml property and then parse the the content again in System.Xml.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that if you can avoid it. Microsoft explicitly does not support mixing MSXML with .NET

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815112